# ServerSentEvents, HttpTaskAsyncHandler and waiting

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, async-await

I'm trying to create a quite simple notifications system (don't want to use SignalIR or something else). I have the following testing code:

Client side:

```
var source = new EventSource('/notifications.axd');

source.onopen = function () {
    Console.log("Connection open");
};

source.onerror = function () {
    Console.log("Connection error");
};

source.onmessage = function (event) {
    Console.log("Message: " + event.data);
};
```

Server side:

```
public class NotificationMessage {
    public NotificationMessage() {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public string Id { get; private set; }
}

public class NotificationsHandler : HttpTaskAsyncHandler {
    private const string CONTENT_TYPE = "text/event-stream";

    private sealed class NotificationItem {
        public ConcurrentQueue<NotificationMessage> Messages;
        public CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource;
    }

    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, NotificationItem> _tasks =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, NotificationItem>();

    public static void Notify(string hostId, string userId, NotificationMessage message) {
        NotificationItem item;
        if (!_tasks.TryGetValue(string.Format("{0}|{1}", hostId, userId), out item)) {
            return;
        }

        var tokenSource = item.CancellationTokenSource;
        item.Messages.Enqueue(message);
        item.CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        tokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    public override async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context) {
        HttpRequest request = context.Request;

        NotificationItem item = _tasks.GetOrAdd(
            string.Format("{0}|{1}", request.Url.Host, CsSession.Data.CurrentUser.Id), 
            k => new NotificationItem {
                Messages = new ConcurrentQueue<NotificationMessage>(),
                CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource()
            }
        );

        HttpResponse response = context.Response;

        response.ContentType = CONTENT_TYPE;
        response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
        response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        response.AppendHeader("connection", "keep-alive");

        response.BufferOutput = false;
        bool supportsAsyncFlush = response.SupportsAsyncFlush;
        bool shouldPing = true;

        while (response.IsClientConnected) {
            try {
                NotificationMessage message = null;
                if ((!item.Messages.IsEmpty && item.Messages.TryDequeue(out message)) || shouldPing) {
                    response.Write(string.Format("data:{0}\n\n", message == null ? "{}" : JsonMapper.Serialize(message)));

                    if (supportsAsyncFlush) {
                        await Task.Factory.FromAsync(response.BeginFlush, response.EndFlush, null);

                    } else {
                        response.Flush();
                    }
                } 

            } catch (Exception) {
                break;
            }

            var delay = Task.Delay(15000, item.CancellationTokenSource.Token);
            await delay;
            shouldPing = delay.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is: the above doesn't works. I have two issues:

1) When the client connects, I receive an empty packet (that's ok). Then, if I don't enqueue any messages, after awaiting the Task.Delay, the loop tries to write an empty message again, but I don't know where. The response.Write line never returns (and nothing is being received on the client).

2) If I write to the queue, for some reason the connection is dropped. If I put a breakpoint on the line after the await delay, that line is never executed (while my logic says otherwise :) ). If I cancel the token, the delay task should quit, but it seems it is aborting the whole handler??

Comment: Answering myself: solved (1). Instead of doing an await delay, I'm now doing an await delay.ConfigureAwait(false);
Writing to the queue stills drop the connection...

Comment: You know ASP.NET wasn't designed for this, right? So there's likely not going to be anything "quite simple" about the solution. "don't want to use SignalIR" - why not? SignalR *is* designed for this.

Comment: Well, SignalIR does something quite similar if websockets is not available (it uses the same type of connection on the client and does something similar on the server), so that's not really an issue.